# Can a group have more than one operation? If not, what is the operation of a dihedral group?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

In my 1st year Mathematics BSc course, dihedral groups seems to include rotations and reflections, which suggests that groups can have more than one operation. But definitions of groups I've seen seem to suggest (not totally clearly) that groups have exactly one operation.

If that's right, what's the single operation associated with dihedral groups? I would guess it's reflection, since rotations can be retrieved from compositions of reflections, but not the reverse.

Comment: I think is this context the group operation is **composition**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please be careful. In the context of groups (and more generally, algebras in the sense of General/Universal Algebra), an “operation” is something you do to elements of your set. So for a group $G$, an “operation” (or more specifically, a binary operation) for the group is usually understood to mean a function $G\times G\to G$, and more, it is understood to mean the function $G\times G\to G$ that has the properties that makes $G$ into a group. For the dihedral group, this operation is “composition”.

Instead, what you are talking about are the ways the group *acts* on something (for the dihedral group, the way it acts on a regular $n$-gon); the elements of the dihedral group have two different types of *actions* on the regular $n$-gon, the rotations (which preserve orientation) and the reflections (which reverse orientation).

---

Note that while groups are usually defined with a single binary operation, as follows:

> A group is a set $G$ together with a binary operation $\cdot\colon G\times G\to G$, usually written in infix notation, such that:
>
> 1. For all $a,b,c\in G$, $(a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c)$ ($\cdot$ is associative);
> 2. There exists $e\in G$ such that for all $a\in G$, $e\cdot a = a\cdot e = a$ ($\cdot$ has an identity element);
> 3. For every $a\in G$ there exists $b\in G$ such that $a\cdot b=b\cdot a = e$ (every element has a $\cdot$-inverse).

However, from the viewpoint of Universal Algebra, groups are actually sets with *three* operations: a binary, a unary, and nullary operation (two, one, and zero inputs). As follows:

> A group is an ordered pair $(G,\Omega)$, where $\Omega=\{\cdot,{}^{-1},e\}$ consists of a binary operation $\cdot$ on $G$, a unary operation ${}^{-1}$ on $G$, and a nullary operation $e$ on $G$, such that:
>
> 1. $\cdot$ is associative;
> 2. $a\cdot e = e\cdot a = a$ for all $a\in G$;
> 3. $a\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot a= e$ for all $a\in G$.

Comment: [Note that closure of $\cdot$ is implied by the fact that it's a binary operation from $G\times G$ to $G$.]

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer. From reading the starts of the wikipedia articles on group action and homomorphism, I interpret you to mean: rotations and reflections are functions $\text{rot}:A\mapsto B$ and $\text{ref}:A\mapsto B$, where $A$ is the dihedral group and $B$ is the group of transformations on the regular $n$-gon. 1) Is that right, and, if so, 2) what are the elements of the dihedral group, and 3) what are the relevant transformations of the regular $n$-gon if not rotations and reflections?

Comment: @mjc: No, rotations and reflections are functions from the regular $n$-gon to itself; in your notation, they are each functions $A\to A$. $B$ would be the group. You don’t map into the group. The rotations and reflections are **elements** of $B$, and they **act** on $A$ by sending $A$ to itself.

Comment: @mjc: The elements of the dihedral group of order $2n$, which consists of the rigid motions of the regular $n$ gon, are the $n$ rotations (including the identity) and the $n$ reflections (about the $n$ axes of symmetry of the regular $n$-gon). They are **each** a function from the regular $n$-gon to itself. None of them map “into” the dihedral group. They *are* the “relevant transformations” (namely, the rigid motions) of the regular $n$-gon.

Comment: How's this? Define: 1) $S_n$, the regular $n$-gon; 2) $R_n$, the set of rotations and reflections about the axes of symmetry of $S_n$, with each element of $R_n$ being a function $r:S_n\mapsto S_n$ acting on $S_n$; 3) $C$, the binary operation of composition, $C:R_n^2\mapsto R_n$ given by $C(r_1,r_2)=r_1\circ r_2$. Then the dihedral group associated with $S_n$ is $D_n=(R_n,C)$.

Comment: @mjc: Ugh. $S_n$ already has a meaning in group theory $S_n$ is the group of all permutations of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So.... not. Don’t do that. “The set of rotations and reflections” also already has a name, it’s called the dihedral group, and it is denoted either as $D_{2n}$ or $D_n$ (both are common). And composition is denoted by $\circ$, don’t use $C$. The group is $(D_n,\circ)$.

Comment: @mjc: Here is the typical way: imagine the regular $n$-gon as lying on the plane, inscribed in the unit circle, with one vertex at $(1,0)$. Number the vertices starting with that vertex being $v_1$, going counterclockwise until you get to $v_n$. Then the dihedral group $D_n$ (or $D_{2n}$ depending on your convention) consists of the elements $1,r,\ldots,r^{n-1},s,rs,\ldots,r^{n-1}s$, where $r$ is the rotation that sends $v_1\mapsto v_2$, $v_2\mapsto v_3,\ldots,v_{n}\mapsto v_n$, and $s$ is the reflection about the $x$-axis; $r^i$ means “apply $r$, $i$ times”, and $r^js$ is the composition.

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear. I think the last detail I'm looking for (which was actually the motivation for the OP) is to know what $A$ should be in the definition $D_n:=(A,\circ)$. That is, how to notationally distinguish the group from the set for the purpose of defining one in terms of the other.

Comment: @mjc: Almost *nobody* distinguishes the group from its underlying set except in very specific circumstances. You almost invariably refer to the group by the name of its underlying set, the operations being understood from context. It clutters notation way too much to keep them separate. About the only person I know who manages to keep the distinction throughout an entire book is George Bergman in his book on Universal Algebra, and this is described as “some kind of magical alchemy” in the MathReview for the book. Everyone else just abuses notation for ease.

Answer (score 5):

The operation associated with the dihedral group is combining transformations. For example, given an $n$-gon, I can first rotate it and then reflect it. Rotation is one member of the group, reflection - another, and their product in the group is the combined transformation.

Answer (score 3):

A group $(G,\star)$ has only one operation, which is the binary operation $\star$ between its elements. If a group $G$ contains bijective maps from some fixed set $X$ to itself (such as geometric transformations of the plane are, or the permutations of a set of $n$ elements) then the operation of the group is the composition of functions $f\circ g$, where $f\circ g$ is the function mapping $x\mapsto f(g(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with all the good answers by Arturo and Gae, there is still another angle at this for finite groups.

Given a finite group $G$ with the binary operation $\cdot$, one can construct, using that operation, *another* operation on the same underlying set. What I am alluding to is the so-called **Baer Trick**: suppose that for the finite group $(G,\cdot)$, $G/Z(G)$ is abelian and $|G|$ is odd. Then there exists an  operation $x \star y$, defined for elements $x,y \in G$, that turns $(G,\star)$ into an *abelian* group! In this construction, surprisingly, the order of an element in $(G,\cdot)$ equals its order in $(G,\star)$. The Baer Trick is used for example in the theory of coprime actions of groups (see also [Kurzweil-Stellmacher, *The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwixs_DQzfnoAhUD6aQKHfuOCzAQFjABegQICBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.math.ku.dk%2F~olsson%2Fmanus%2FGruFus%2FKurzweil-Stellmacher_Theory%2520of%2520finite%2520groups.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1kfxOy7ZSGJUB7maLh6mh7), Chapter 8.5)